# How can we compare the hash value of file in local path and same file uploaded on sharepoint site?

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, hashcode, .net-framework-version

I'm working with C#, Framework 4.6.1 (VS 2015).
I am using Microsoft.Graph api to upload a file from local path to Sharepoint site. After uploading the file I need to compare the hash value of file in local path with the same file uploaded to sharepoint site.
I tried MD5 algorithm with System.Net.Webclient as shown below:

WebClient client = new WebClient();

```
            using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
            {
                using (var stream = client.OpenRead(uri))
                {
                    var hash = md5.ComputeHash(stream);
                    return BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", "").ToLowerInvariant();
                }
            }
```

I have done the authentication before calling this method using Microsoft.Graph api (registering an app on azure active directory portal) but even after this I am getting below error:
"The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."

Can anyone please help me with how can I find and compare the hash value of the file in local path and after uploading the same file to sharepoint site?

Note : This is I am implementing just to verify whether file is uploaded successfully or not.

Answer (score 0):

OneDrive Rest API supports [hash](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/resources/hashes?view=odsp-graph-online). Also, highly recommend checking this [question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/251520/sharepoint-online-file-md5-sha256-md5-checksum). However, SharePoint can add some metadata to some file types that may affect your hash.